# clojure NullPointerException when def a vector

Tags: clojure

Something wrong with

```
(def b [08])
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

but

```
(def b [8])
```

is OK

why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know nothing about clojure, but in many languages, an integer literal that starts with a zero is interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8). And 8 is an invalid octal digit.

From a quick experiment at [Try Clojure](http://tryclj.com/):

```
> (def b [08])
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: 08
> (def b [07])
#'sandbox155/b
```

It appears that this is indeed your problem.

Don't start integers with a leading zero (e.g. `08`), unless you *actually* intend octal notation.

Answer (score 2):

@Jonathon Reinhart is right, according to the LispReader.java :(https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L65) :

`static Pattern intPat =
                Pattern.compile(
                                "([-+]?)(?:(0)|([1-9][0-9]*)|0[xX]([0-9A-Fa-f]+)|0([0-7]+)|([1-9][0-9]?)[rR]([0-9A-Za-z]+)|0[0-9]+)(N)?");`

The part `0([0-7]+)` in the pattern prove this.